# why show "Undefined" below "Hello World"?

Tags: javascript

[why show "Undefined"  below  "Hello World"?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gvhH.png)

```js
let Object_A = {};
Object_A.Func_01 = function() {
  console.log("Hello World");
}
console.log(Object_A.Func_01());
```

Comment: `console.log` does not return anything, it just shows its value in the console

Comment: Because the function doesn't return anything so logging "no return value" is `undefined`.

Comment: because `Func_01` doesn't return anything and you're logging the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

It's because by saying `console.log(object.function())` you are printing the return value of the function (which is `undefined` because you haven't returned anything specifically). If you want to just print the hello word it's enough to call the function `object.function()` cause it is already doing that.